# Extract some interested part of list value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

From this list

```
List = ['/asd/dfg/ert.py','/wer/cde/xcv.img']
```

Got this

```
List = ['ert.py','xcv.img']
```

Answer (score 6):

There's a low-level `split`-based approach:

```
>>> a = ['/asd/dfg/ert.py','/wer/cde/xcv.img']
>>> b = [elem.split("/")[-1] for elem in a]
>>> b
['ert.py', 'xcv.img']
```

Or a higher-level, more descriptive approach, which is probably more robust:

```
>>> import os
>>> b = [os.path.basename(filename) for filename in a]
>>> b
['ert.py', 'xcv.img']
```

Of course this assumes that I've guessed right about what you wanted; your example is somewhat underspecified.

Answer (score -1):

```
$List = array('/asd/dfg/ert.py','/wer/cde/xcv.img');
$pattern = "#/.*/#";
foreach ($List AS $key => $str)
  $List[$key] = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);

print_r($List);
```

Comment: That's obviously a dialect of Python 2.7 I'm not familiar with. ;-)

Comment: my mistake thought it is a php question anyway you can use the concept